# React child component not re-rendered with prop coming from redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm currently playing with [react-simple-maps](https://www.react-simple-maps.io/) to display a world map containing countries.

I try to do the following scenario:

- I have a world map with each country filled by blue color
- I click on a country
- It triggers `selectCountry(country)` action and update redux store with the selected country
- I get the selected country and highlight it in green

All redux stuff work because the state is updated and I get the country selected in my `country` prop.

My issue is that the `<Geography>` component is not re-rendered and not filled with the green color even if I use the following code :

```
style={{ default: {fill: country.NAME === geography.properties.NAME ? 'green' : 'blue' }}}
```

How I can re-render the `Geography` component (just the country selected) to fill it with the green color ? Am I forced to use [forceUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate)?

Here is my file :

**Worldmap.jsx**

```
import topoWorldMap from '../../data/world-110m.json';

const Worldmap = ({ country, selectCountry }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ComposableMap
        projectionConfig={{
          scale: 205,
          rotation: [-11, 0, 0]
        }}
        width={980}
        height={551}
      >
        <ZoomableGroup center={[0, 20]} disablePanning>
          <Geographies geography={topoWorldMap}>
            {(geographies, projection) =>
              geographies.map(geography => (
                <Geography
                  onClick={() => selectCountry(geography.properties)}
                  key={geography.properties.NAME}
                  geography={geography}
                  projection={projection}
                  style={{
                    default: {
                      fill: country.NAME === geography.properties.NAME ? 'green' : 'blue'
                    }
                  }}
                />
              ))
            }
          </Geographies>
        </ZoomableGroup>
      </ComposableMap>
    </div>
  );
};

Worldmap.defaultProps = {
  country: {}
};

Worldmap.propTypes = {
  country: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any),
  selectCountry: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

Thanks by advance,

Comment: seems to work fine (*see https://codesandbox.io/s/map-chart-with-tooltip-ukb4f*) when country is stored in the parents state. Are you completely sure you are passing it down correctly ?

Comment: In fact the problem was linked to an older react-simple-maps version, I've updated with the last one and it's working now thank you !

Answer (score 2):

> I get the country selected in my country prop

The way React works is that when a prop changes, the component is re-rendered. So if this is true, your component is actually re-rendered.

So maybe :

- your render function doesn't give a different UI when country changes (are you sure about the "default" field in style ?)
- actually the country prop doesn't change (you can debug this by setting a `<span>{country.toString()}</span>` in the render function), then make sure you use react-redux with `connect(mapStateToProps)` properly

Cheers

Comment: In fact the problem was linked to an older react-simple-maps version, I've updated with the last one and it's working now thank you !

Answer (score 1):

If the country changes then the component WILL re-render. Double-check that you are passing country correctly (i.e make sure the value changed otherwise it won't re-render)

Check your reducer to make sure it is

- being called
- doing something with the state
- returns the new state (not the one passed)

Since the state is immutable; the resulting state from a reducer is a copy of the current state plus the new data

Comment: In fact the problem was linked to an older react-simple-maps version, I've updated with the last one and it's working now thank you !